# How to update an expireSub field of mongoDB in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

```
     for (let j = 0; j < result[i].subscription.length; j++) {
          let re = await userdetails.updateOne(
            { _id: result[i]._id },
            { $set: { subscription: { [j]: { $set: { expireSub: true } } } } }
          )};
```

[image: code]

Update an `expireSub` field of mongoDB.

Comment: You want to update all the expireSub value present inside subscription array to true?

Comment: yes, I want to update expireSub:true of all subscription array

Answer (score 0):

Use the all operator `$[]`:

```
$set: { "subscription.$[].expireSub": true }
```

More info: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/

Comment: How can I update only at index [0] not all the array

Comment: Use this `$set: { "subscription.0.expireSub": true }`

Comment: How can I update document depend on j value means if j=0 update at index [0] and if j=2 update index [2]